# CSS linear animation across screen

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-animations

I have a car which im moving to the right of the screen. (the car needs to start from left infinity and go out of the screen on the right).

But the animation repeats just once and stops.

```
<div class="car-right">
   <img class="car-right-image"src="/assets/car-right.png" alt="">
</div>

.car-right {
  position: absolute;
  top: 86%;
  left: -200px;
  z-index: 10;
}
.transit-right {
  -webkit-transform: translate(1920px,0);
  -webkit-transition: all 30s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 30s ease-in-out;
  z-index: 10;
}

$(function() {
  return $('.car-right-image').addClass("transit-right");
});
```

What am i doing wrong here ? ... how do i make the car keep coming from the left infinity and dissapear to the right ? ...

I know i gotta do something with keyframes and the infinite atrribute.

But cant seem to get it ...

Any help is highly appreciated, thanks.

Regards
-Skykog

Comment: **"I know i gotta do something with keyframes and the infinite atrribute."** So you know the answer but won't put the work in? **Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: Stack Overflow question checklist.**

Comment: CSS3 Transitions are different from Animations. You're currently using Transitions, but it sounds like you want Animations (which allow for keyframes).

Comment: [Learn the basics of CSS animation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_animations). There is no need for javascript

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/video-screencasts/97-intro-to-css-animations/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use CSS Animations not transitions.

```
.car-right {
  position: absolute;
  top: 86%;
  left: -200px;
  z-index: 10;
  background-color: red;
  animation-duration: 4s;
  animation-name: goRight;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@keyframes goRight {
  from {
    transform: translate(0,0);
  }

  to {
    transform: translate(1920px,0);
  }
}
```

There is no need for jQuery for this.
Here is a demo running at a 4 seconds interval: http://jsfiddle.net/NrLy8/1/

Comment: Hey, thanks for helping out .... but this didnt work .... i added the same, even tried with vendor prefix

Comment: It does work on the fiddle in Chrome. Did you tried the fiddle? http://jsfiddle.net/NrLy8/1/

Comment: Hii ....thanks :) ...this is what finally worked, http://jsfiddle.net/F7s33/ 

But i got guidance from you ... so thanks a bunch again :) ....

Answer (score 1):

jQuery solution, here's a <kbd>**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mdesdev/DLTEv/)**</kbd>

```
.car-right-image {
  position: absolute;
  width: 260px;
  left: -260px;
}


$(function() {
  setInterval(function() {
    $('.car-right-image').animate({ left: $(window).width() + 'px' }, 3000, 'linear', function() {
      $(this).css({ left: - $(this).width() + 'px' });
    });
  }, 10);
});
```